# Why I receive 'object is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my nodejs app, inside User mongoose schema I have this method:

```
/*
 * Passport-Local Mongoose will add a username, hash and salt field to store the username, the hashed password and the salt value.
 */
var User = new Schema({
  email: String,
  token: String,
  twitter: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    displayName: String,
  }
});

    /*
 * Find user by twitter id.
 */
User.statics.findOrCreateByTwitterId = function (token, tokenSecret, profile, fn) {
  this.findOne({
    'twitter.id': profile.id
  }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn(err, null);
    if (user) {
      return fn(null, user)
    };

    // create user
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.username = profile.username;
    newUser.twitter.id = profile.id;
    newUser.token = token;
    newUser.displayName = profile.displayName;

    // create user
    newUser.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return fn(null, null);
      }
      return fn(null, newUser)

    });

  });
};

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

When it is called I receive:

```
2015-02-24T07:47:24.162Z - debug: Mongoose:  -  users  -  findOne  -  { 'twitter.id': '90411931' } 
2015-02-24T07:47:24.327Z - error: Caught exception:  TypeError: object is not a function
```

where line 32 is:

```
var newUser = new User();
```

Do you see any issue?

Comment: I think... we need to see more code... specially where you created your `User`.

Comment: the error suggests that `User` is not a reference to a function, but a reference to a variable

Comment: According to [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) you should convert your schema (`User`) to a model first using `var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);`

Comment: User has the reference of new Schema(), which is an object. and when you are doing new User() then it will give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... mongoose.Schema can not be instantiated. You need to create a model from the schema like this,

```
var UserModel = mongoose.model( 'UserModel', User );
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference the current model from within a schema, you can do `var newUser = new this.constructor();`

Answer (score 0):

To create a new user, you need to `new` the model, not the `User` schema.  So save off the initial `this` in the static function that's the model so it's not lost once inside the `findOne` callback and then use that to create the user:

```
User.statics.findOrCreateByTwitterId = function (token, tokenSecret, profile, fn) {
  var model = this;
  model.findOne({
    'twitter.id': profile.id
  }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn(err, null);
    if (user) {
      return fn(null, user)
    };

    // create user
    var newUser = new model();
    newUser.username = profile.username;
    newUser.twitter.id = profile.id;
    newUser.token = token;
    newUser.displayName = profile.displayName;

    // create user
    newUser.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return fn(null, null);
      }
      return fn(null, newUser)

    });

  });
};
```